# Sharepoint Document Library Corrupted

Tags: document-library, 2019

There is a document library in one of our sites and when we try to open it. The browser is filled with all weird values and words from inside the documents in the library. Has anyone faced this issue, I checked the logs as well when accessing this library but nothing in it. Any help is appreciated. Also I am not able to save this library as a template because of the size issue, so I could create a new one and see if the same issue is being replicated.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the URL (you may mask the url and left the suffix) to get above page? Have you installed OOS (office online server)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response chris, no we don't have OOS installed. Here is the URL

Comment: /Forms/AllItems.aspx